# Book request-Riemannian geometry and control theory

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a book dealing with Riemannian geometry with a control point of view.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Andrei Agrachev, Yuri Sachkov: *Control Theory from the Geometric Viewpoint*.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does, in fact, answer the question.